# youtube/v3/search - id.kind criteria

Tags: youtube-api

Is there a way I can specify the `id.kind` criteria along with the other criteria in `youtube/v3/search`?

I tried entering the parameter `&id.kind=youtube#video` in my get url it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the search endpoint, you can filter the type of resource returned with the "type" parameter; if you set it to "channel," for example, you'll only get back resources where the id.kind value is "youtube#channel."

Acceptable values for the "type" parameter of a search are "channel," "video," or "playlist," and you can search on multiple types with a comma-delimited list of the types you want back.